# "No resource found that matches the given name" when I gradlew assembleDebug

Tags: firebase, react-native

I've cloned the [react-native-hackathon-starter](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-hackathon-starter) repo, wrote my own little app and tried to build an apk for debug using gradle assembleDebug, but I get this exception:

> path\to\project\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\10.2.1\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.xml:3:29-91 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background').
>   path\to\project\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\10.2.1\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.xml:3:29-92 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background').
>   path\to\project\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\10.2.1\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml:3:29-91 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background').
>   path\to\project\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\10.2.1\res\drawable\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml:3:29-92 : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background').

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-firestack:processReleaseResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':react-native-firestack:processReleaseResources'.

From what I can tell, it's missing some graphical resources. I've tried gradlew clean before assemble, it still doesn't fix the issue.

Someone else has the same  [issue](https://github.com/fullstackreact/FirestackApp/issues/16) as me.

My package.json:

```
{
"name": "HackathonStarter",
"version": "0.0.2",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
},
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^3.6.7",
    "native-base": "^2.1.0",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.4.2",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.1.8",
    "react-native-firestack": "^2.3.9",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.37.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^5.1.7",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "~15.5.4",
    "react-native": "0.43.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.5.4"
},
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
}
```

}

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I hate to even ask, but did you npm install after you cloned the repo? I have also cloned that repo and successfully ran it with android.

Comment: @RyanPfister I did, I made sure all packages are installed, did a gradlew clean and gradlew assembleRelease, it worked once, hasn't worked since. I'm trying again now after deleting node_modules and making an npm install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deleting the node_modules folder, doing another npm install, removing node_modules/react-native-router-flux/react-native and editing out

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+

from node_modules/react-native-firestack/android/build.gradle, because it was causing interference with the gms dependency in my root build.gradle, I was able to do a gradlew assembleDebug and assembleRelease.

I think there was a problem with the firestack package, not bundling assets together correctly or whatever. All good now.